# How to accept attachment from LINE user in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I use one click integration in dialogflow + google cloud function for fulfillment. I want to accept user attachment in LINE chat platform. 
If I use Facebook messenger, I can use `FACEBOOK_MEDIA` event to trigger the intent when user uploading some files.

Is there any event that can help me do the same for LINE platform? Or is there any way to trigger dialogflow intent when LINE user upload some files to my chatbot?

Comment: any luck with this argument?

Comment: nope, still no solution